# Copy bytes from one array to another

Tags: c#, byte, networkstream

I'm trying to copy a specific amount of bytes from one byte array, to another byte array, I've searched through numerous answers to similar questions, but can't seem to find a solution.

Basic example of code,

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

byte[] store;
```

if I do

```
Console.WriteLine(bytes);
```

it will return the number of bytes read from stream which is

```
24
```

which is the only bytes I would need to pass over to the ' store ' array.. but of course if i specify

```
byte[] store = data;
```

then it will take 1024 bytes, 1000 of which are empty.

so what I want really is something like

```
byte[] store = (data, 0, bytes);
```

which would provide store 24 bytes from the data array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Array.Copy`:

```
byte[] newArray = new byte[length];
Array.Copy(oldArray, startIndex, newArray, 0, length);
```

or `Buffer.BlockCopy`:

```
byte[] newArray = new byte[length];
Buffer.BlockCopy(oldArray, startIndex, newArray, 0, length);
```

Or LINQ:

```
var newArray = oldArray
.Skip(startIndex) // skip the first n elements
.Take(length) // take n elements
.ToArray(); // produce array
```

[Try them online](https://rextester.com/PNWH23936)

Alternatively, if you're using C# 7.2 or newer (and have the System.Memory NuGet package referenced if you're using .NET Framework), you could use [`Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.-ctor?view=netstandard-2.1#System_Span_1__ctor__0___System_Int32_System_Int32_):

```
var newArray = new Span<byte>(oldArray, startIndex, length).ToArray();
```

Or, if you want, you can just pass the `Span<T>` around without converting it to an array.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
byte[] Slice(byte[] source, int start, int len)
{
    byte[] res = new byte[len];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        res[i] = source[i + start];
    }

    return res;
}
```